# Finding a number sequence in an integer

Tags: python-3.x

Guys heres my problem:

I am trying to read an integer from the user(e.g. 12345)

How can i check if the pattern "34" exists in the first integer?

My constraint is that i cannot convert it to string and cannot use arrays.

Here is what i managed to write to print some of the patterns that exists in 12345:

```
import math

int1 = int(input("input an integer: "))

#I used this to find out how many digits are in the integer
count = math.ceil(math.log10(int1))

for i in range(count): 
    print (int1 % (10 ** (i+1)))

for i in range(count):
    print (int1 // (10 ** (i+1)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.3 extract short digit sequences from the integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767286/python-3-3-extract-short-digit-sequences-from-the-integer). You guys should get in touch, it looks like you're taking the same classes.

Comment: Thank you, it appears his problem is the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be homework, I won't provide an answer, but only a rough hint.

Hint: extract each digit of the number using `divmod(n, 10)`, which returns n without the last digit and the last digit of n. Hold the current digit and the previous digit in variables and compare them with the pattern, `34`, each time a new a digit is extracted.